# Github pull request to private repo (from my own branch)

Tags: git, github

Pretty green with Github but the suggestions I've found so far aren't working.

I'm adding a new feature to a private Github repo. I was instructed to create a branch and submit a pull request.

I added the repo in Github's desktop client and created a new branch, `new-feature`. I've made all the changes, but when I try to publish them to the branch I get:

```
 Repository not found!

 'new-feature' doesn’t seem to exist at https://github.com/username/main-name.git/ anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.
```

I can see in my browser that the repo is still at that address, but I suppose I don't have write access.

What's the correct process for getting this to work? Am I supposed to clone the repo into my own account (as a private repo) and submit a pull request from there? I've tried that but can find no way to link this to the main repo, perhaps I've cloned it incorrectly...

Comment: Where do you have this `new-feature` branch? Is this on your own machine? Can you see this branch at your Github repository? There's a dropdown box `Branch: master` near the top left. There you can see, which branches are in your Github repository.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a fork of the project on GitHub.
   Don't worry, your work will be still private.
2. Push your work to your fork. There, you have write permission.
3. Create the Pull Request from the branch in your fork.

Comment: This is what I've attempted to do, but it turns out I didn't properly clone the damn thing! Stupid desktop client. Got it working, thanks mate.

Comment: I have same problem. I set up a private repo. I can't fork it because it says I own it and I'm not a member of any organizations. So what's the solution then?